# Network interface name: "/var/log/dmesg" vs "/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules"

Tags: udev, dmesg

Is it more reliable to look up the association between interface name and MAC address in `/var/log/dmesg` or in `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`?

On Debian 7 or CentOS 7, out of the box, I can find that out by issuing `egrep "[0-9|a-f][0-9|a-f]:[0-9|a-f][0-9|a-f]:[0-9|a-f][0-9|a-f]:[0-9|a-f][0-9|a-f]" /var/log/dmesg`. For each interface I'll get a match indicating name and MAC address.

What I want is to be certain about the name of an interface. Especially on hosts with more than one network interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dmesg` is more authoritative than `70-persistent-net.rules`. `dmesg` indicates how things were actually on the box at the time of boot. The udev rules file is a config file on the filesystem.

If you just want to associate MAC with interface name, the easiest way would be to look at the `ip link show` information. That gives the interface name and the associated MAC address.

Another way would be to look at `/sys/class/net/em1/address`. Replace `em1` with whatever interface you're wanting to check.